# return only records to a report that are marked with a zero or a one

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a drug screen database that is using Number Types zeros and ones for substances that are tested and blank if not tested. I need to create a report that will return specific substances tested for each person and the result (i.e.: if 0 the substance was tested for, and it is negative, if 1 the substance was tested for, and it is positive, if blank the substance was not tested for.

Microsoft Access 16. I have report working for DOT results because they always test for the same substances, which I have each substance field in my report. I cannot get non-DOT to work because there are many possible substances that could potentially be selected for testing. I would like the report to pull for each person what substances they were tested for (only. i.e. each company tests for different substances) and the result.

A line for each substance that can be tested for DOT (i.e.: Marijuana, Cocaine, Amphetamines, PCP, Opioids, etc). Non-DOT has many more potential substances.
`=IIf([Amphetamines]="1","Positive",IIf([Amphetamines]="0","Negative","Cancelled"))`
Header:
`=Switch([Negative]="1","NEGATIVE" & IIf([Dilute]="1","/DILUTE","") & "  RESULT",[Positive]="1","POSITIVE" & IIf([Dilute]="1","/DILUTE","") & "  RESULT",[Cancelled]="1","CANCELLED TEST")`

I can't figure out how to have the report only list substances specific to a test. I only want the specific substances that are tested to return on the report. On the DOT all substances are set always (never add or delete substances).

I have included images [MROReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ZNu.jpg)of the DOT report. But again, DOT substances never change. Non-DOT do.

Comment: Exactly what errors? If field is number type, don't put parameters within quote marks.

Comment: The above works for DOT, which has only and always 5 substances.

Comment: The non-DOT is where I am having problems. It has the potential for only one substance to be tested, up to 16 substances to be tested. I only want what specific substances each individual screen has been tested for and not all the substances. I need the report to state the name of the substance and whether or not the substance was found (Positive), or not (Negative).

Comment: The fields are number type.

Comment: The number Types are also used at the end of the month to tally each company's positives, negatives, etc.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data.